# How to apply CSS style to class which is in another classes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML elements:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3">
    <div class="innerClass">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply style to `innerClass` which is in classes : `class1`, `class2` , `class3` no more no less. I mean if there is `innerClass` in element with classes `class1`, `class2` the style should't be applied and if I have `innerClass` in element with classes `class1`, `class2` , `class3` , `class4` it shouldn't be applied either.

Comment: what a confusing question...:(

Comment: what style you will try to apply?

Comment: Look into sub classes and next time you post please post relevant code (Something you've tried towards the solution.)

Comment: @AnoopLL it's not confusing, OP is asking how to apply CSS to innerClass when its parent has exactly the 3 classes mentioned.

Comment: possible with the CSS attribute selector (see my answer)

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with the **CSS Attribute selector**

> The [attribute] selector is used to select elements with a specified attribute.

```css
div[class="class1 class2 class3"] .inner {padding:1em; background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2 class3">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="class3 class4">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors (added by: [Chris Bier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84292/chris-bier))

---

**Edit:** As pointed about in the comments by [Sidney Liebrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579774/how-to-apply-css-style-to-class-which-is-in-another-classes/35579842#comment58846534_35579842), this approach assumes that the order of the classes is exact and therefore will not work when the order is the following: `class="class2 class3 class1"`. One way to solve this is to just add each order combination possible in the rule, like so:

```
div[class="class1 class2 class3"] .inner,
div[class="class1 class3 class2"] .inner,
div[class="class2 class1 class3"] .inner,
div[class="class2 class3 class1"] .inner,
div[class="class3 class1 class2"] .inner,
div[class="class3 class2 class1"] .inner {
 padding:1em; background:red;
}
```

But as you can see, this is **not efficient** at all so you'll have to make sure the order is correct or resort to a javascript solution.

Comment: wasn't me but I'm guessing it's because this would apply to the child if the parent element also had the class4 (I was also wondering why the downvote and had to read the question again)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can you really understand that question?

Comment: @Aziz this does quite a good job if the classes are correctly applied but if for instance the classes are like this: `class2 class1 class3` then you're not going to get your styles applied either so it would be very structurally limited ;)

Comment: Wow that is an interesting solution that I didn't think of. Nice work

Comment: I agree with @SidneyLiebrand, but I think this is as close as we'll get to matching the question requirements.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand you are completely right, I updated answer to address this issue.

Answer (score 4):

If order of classes is quite randomized, you could filter it using:

```
$('.class1.class2.class3').filter(function(){
   return this.classList.length === 3;
}).find('.innerClass').css({prop: value});
```

You could find polyfill for older browser regarding `classList` support or just split `className`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd combine the classes like this:

```
.class1.class2.class3 .innerClass {

}
```

Comment: Some crazy user out there!

Comment: Yeah, someone is in a bad mood today. Anyway my answer is wrong based on the confusing question so I'm revising.

Comment: @aziz solution is the only way as wildcard selector won't work

Answer (score 1):

Aziz posted the best answer in my opinion, but here is another way to do it.

```
.class1.class2.class3:not(.class4) .innerClass {
       /* Style here */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

This is only supported by IE9+

Comment: and if there is class5?

Comment: Just continue adding `:not` pseudo classes for all cases. It seems like that OP has little to no control over the CSS which is clearly a problem and will make for messy CSS

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. There is an issue, that you can notice on the 3rd square 'same mixed': it only works if the classes are writen on this order.

```css
div[class='class1 class2 class3'] > .innerClass { 
  background-color: gold;
}

.innerClass {
  margin:5px;
  width:100px; 
  height:100px;
  float:left
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2">  
<div class="innerClass" style="outline:2px solid black">one class less</div>
</div>

<div class="class1 class2 class3">
<div class="innerClass" style="outline:2px solid black">exact classes</div>
</div>

<div class="class2 class3 class1">
<div class="innerClass" style="outline:2px solid black">same mixed</div>
</div>

<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4">
<div class="innerClass" style="outline:2px solid black">one class more</div>
</div>
```